# Read blocks of 1000 bytes from file in php

Tags: php, arrays, file

How do I read 1000 bytes blocks into any array from file using a php ?
Once I read all file, I need to access 1000 bytes blocks through each of array indices. My algo looks like this:

```
 foreach($files as $file)
{
    $payload=NULL;
    $file_handle = fopen($file, "r");
    $data = fgets($file_handle);
    $payload = $payload.$data;
    if (strlen($payload) == 1000)
    {
        break;
    }
}
```

but I am finding difficulty in reading back from same place where I stopped last time for next 1000 bytes. Any suggestion would be helpful

Comment: Use fread to read a specific number of bytes. EDIT: http://php.net/manual/en/function.fread.php

Comment: can you give also an input file example? it doesn't need the actual data, just the correct format.

Comment: file does not have a specific format. Each line would have a outputs of  some linux command followed by description text.
"ls command to display all files in a directory"

Answer (score 2):

You start off with an empty array and use `fread()` to read chunks of 1000 bytes each time, until it fails doing that or the chunk read becomes smaller than 1000 bytes.

```
$all_data = array();
while (($data = fread($file_handle, 1000)) !== false && strlen($data) == 1000) {
    $all_data[] = $data;
}
fclose($file_handle);
```

If chunks of less than 1000 bytes are okay, you can leave off the second part of the condition:

```
while (($data = fread($file_handle, 1000)) !== false) {
```

Comment: Issue with this code is if file has less than 1000 chars then it does not get into loop.

Comment: @run_time_rookie Then you just leave off the second part of the condition.